# How can I clear NTFS file system level marked as bad sectors?

Tags: ntfs, chkdsk

Just made a sector-level copy of a laptop hard disk (multiple manufacturer partitions - recovery etc.) using `dd` but I had already run `chkdsk /f /r` a number of times on the `C:` and it has re-mapped bad sectors to some re-mapping files.

My question: DD'ing the disk is a bit-by-bit duplication method. So the "new" disk I have DD'd to will have the re-mapped sectors within the files. Is there a way this can be reversed or "cleaned up" so that a disk check will come back clean? At the end of the day the "new" disk doesn't have any bad sectors but (due to the previous disk having errors) the new disk still resembles the old when, in theory, it should be capable of being cleaned.

How can I clear these sectors which are marked as bad on the file system level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the rescan of the `NTFS clusters`.

> chkdsk /b
>
> NTFS only: Clears the list of bad clusters on the volume and rescans all allocated and free clusters for errors. /b includes the functionality of /r. **Use this parameter after imaging a volume to a new hard disk drive.**

quoted from [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc730714%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

A `sector` is the atomic unit of the physical disk. A `cluster` is the atomic unit of NTFS. When a bad sector is found (e.g. by using `chkdsk /r`) the whole cluster(s) lying on the sector are marked as faulty. So the rescan of the clusters is needed.

Comment: You beaut. I'm on it now.